# How to draw a circle in a shader in perspective projection?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d, shader, hlsl

С#

```
var matrix = camera.projectionMatrix * camera.worldToCameraMatrix;
Shader.SetGlobalMatrix("_INVERSE_UNITY_MATRIX_VP", matrix.inverse);  
Shader.SetGlobalMatrix("_UNITY_MATRIX_VP", matrix);
```

HLSL

```
    v2f vert(appdata_full v)
    {
        v2f o;

        o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
        o.uv = v.texcoord.xy;
        return o;
    }
    float DrawSmoothCircle(float2 uv, float2 center, float radius, float blur, float4 scale)
    {
        float2 diff = (uv - center)/(scale.xy/ scale.zw);
        float dist = length(diff);
        float alpha = 1 - saturate(smoothstep(radius, radius + dist * blur, dist));
        return alpha;
    }
    
    half4 frag(v2f i) : SV_Target
    {
        float2 uv = i.uv * 2 - 1;
        float4 uv_world = mul(_INVERSE_UNITY_MATRIX_VP, float4(uv, 0, 1));
        uv_world.z = _Depth;
        uv = mul(_UNITY_MATRIX_VP, uv_world);  
        uv = uv * 0.5 + 0.5;
        
        half4 sceneColor = DrawSmoothCircle(uv, float2(0.5, 0.5), 0.2, 0, float4(1,1,1,1));
        return sceneColor;
    }
```

I'm trying to draw a circle with perspective, but it's not working. There is no change when change _Depth value.I expect the circle to grow distant. What could be the problem?

I use UV in screen space where UV (0,0) is the left-bottom corner.